# How to see size of MySQL internal innodb temporary tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, amazon-aurora

I'm seeing a large number of [internal temporary disk tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) being written. I can see the count with `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS where Variable_name like 'Created_tmp_disk_tables'`.

I know I can update `max_heap_table_size` and `tmp_table_size` to help prevent this, but without knowing the size of the tables getting written to disk, it's difficult to know what values to use.

Does anyone know how to go about finding this value?

Comment: What version of MySQL/Aurora are you using?

Comment: It's aurora version 1.14.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not easy to get. In Percona Server, there are options to add additional information in the slow query log that shows the size of temp tables (see https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/diagnostics/slow_extended.html)

```
# User@Host: mailboxer[mailboxer] @  [192.168.10.165]
# Thread_id: 11167745  Schema: board
# Query_time: 1.009400  Lock_time: 0.000190  Rows_sent: 4  Rows_examined: 1543719  Rows_affected: 0  Rows_read: 4
# Bytes_sent: 278  Tmp_tables: 0  Tmp_disk_tables: 0  Tmp_table_sizes: 0
# QC_Hit: No  Full_scan: Yes  Full_join: No  Tmp_table: No  Tmp_table_on_disk: No
# Filesort: No  Filesort_on_disk: No  Merge_passes: 0
```

(The example above, taken from the Percona documentation, shows the extended fields, although the example is for a query that did not create temp tables, so the size is shown as 0.)

In Oracle MySQL, some of the same extended information is available in query events in the PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA—*but not the temp table sizes.*

In 2014, I logged a feature request to supply this information: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74484 and this bug has been acknowledged, but this has not been implemented as far as I know.

It's a little bit unclear how this would be implemented, since it's possible for any given query to create *multiple* temp tables of different sizes. I believe the Percona feature shows the sum total of the temp table sizes in such cases.

All I can offer as a suggestion is to increase the `max_heap_table_size` and `tmp_table_size` in increments, and monitor the rate of increase of the `Created_tmp_disk_tables` reported by `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`, compared to `Created_tmp_tables` (temp tables that did not use disk). As the allowed tmp table size is able to hold a greater percentage of temp tables created, you should start to see the ratio of on-disk temp tables to in-memory temp tables decrease.

It's typically not necessary to increase `tmp_table_size` to hold *every* possible temp table, no matter how large. You want the largest outliers to use the disk. But as long as the temp tables use memory 98% of the time, you should be fine. That would mean that the ratio of Created_tmp_disk_tables to Created_tmp_tables should be 1:50 or more.

Comment: It does look like a small percentage of the tables are being written to disk (less than 1%). However, it looks like it's resulting in about 1GB of data per day. Do you know if a database restart is the only way to reclaim space consumed by the disk temp tables?

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-temporary-tablespace.html the tmp tablespace is removed during a clean shutdown, so yes, you will have to restart. Some people choose to set `default_tmp_storage_engine=MyISAM` to avoid the InnoDB tmp tablespace.

Answer (score 1):

(Addenda to Bill's Answer.)

Some significant changes have been made in the handling of tmp tables in 5.7 and 8.0.  I am not sure if any of them apply here, but aware.

Exceeding `tmp_table_size` is not the only reason for using a disk-based temp table -- `TEXT`, `BLOB`, `@variables`, `UNION`, etc.  (More details in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html )  For that reason, I would question Bill's 1:50 advice.

Tmp tables (on-disk or in-memory) can be created by lots of queries; multiple tmp tables may be needed for a complex query.  So, the number of simultaneous tmp tables is *potentially* more than `max_connections`.  For this reason, I recommend keeping `tmp_table_size` less than 1% of available RAM.  If you did have a high setting *and* need lots of simultaneous tmp tables, you could cause swapping, which is terribly bad for performance.

There are many "fixes" to having high values for `Created_tmp*tables`; too many to itemize here.  If you would like to present a query (and the relevant `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`); we can discuss that particular case.

When [*analyzing*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis) a customer's system, I look for things such as

```
Created_tmp_disk_tables > 1/second
Created_tmp_disk_tables > 4% of queries
Created_tmp_tables > 20/second
```

Any of those, in my opinion, indicate the need for scrutiny of slow queries.  But if `tmp_table_size` is greater than 1% of RAM, I advise lowering it, even if it hurts some queries.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking through the documentation, and assuming that just knowing the number of tables is not sufficient (looking at `Created_tmp_tables`), the variable [`tmpdir`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmpdir) would give you the location of the directory storing these tables. Lowering [`tmp_table_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmp_table_size) should ensure temp tables are created on disk, so you're able to look at the size.