# How can I get the size of a TEMPORARY MySQL MEMORY table?

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

While inserting rows into a temporary table with `ENGINE=MEMORY` I've come up against the error:

> The table 'tmp' is full

I know I can increase the `max_heap_table_size` variable to overcome this but the trouble is I have no idea how much memory the current data is using.

I've tried `SHOW TABLE STATUS;` but it doesn't seem to include temporary tables.  I've also looked at `information_schema.tables` but again, it doesn't show any information about temporary tables.

How can I get the current usage statistics of a temporary table?

Comment: Have you checked Bill Karwin's answer? He noted that there can be some specific features in your software. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913129/how-to-see-size-of-mysql-internal-innodb-temporary-tables

Comment: I can't go into testing this right now, but you should try enabling and configuring the performance_schema https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema.html. To limit your queries later, you'll need the thread id. You can get the current connection's thread id using `show processlist`. It will be the one who's `Info` is running that command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of this debugging, make it a permanent table long enough to get your answer.  Even bake it in:

```
CREATE /* not TEMPORARY */ TABLE tmp...;
INSERT INTO tmp...;
use `tmp`
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tmp';
DROP TABLE tmp;
```

If this tmp table needs to exist for multiple connections simultaneously, then you have a potentially worse problem -- swapping or running out of memory.  I bring that up rather than discussion how you could make the name `tmp` unique to the connection.

Note that you need to decrease `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (and perhaps other cache limits) to leave enough RAM for you tmp table.  You are "robbing peter to pay paul"; it *may* lead to *worse* overall performance.

Please describe further what you are doing.  It may be that `MEMORY` is not the best solution.

Comment: thanks - in fact what you demonstrated here is exactly what I ended up doing as a one off just to get an idea about the memory used.  the temp table is being built as part of a search engine, so it only holds a list of ids and nothing more, which is then used by several other queries to do joins, filters, & various row counts.  it's then immediately thrown out.  since it's more or less read only data I am currently using myisam, not innodb. at the moment it actually performs quite well, but I was just looking in to using memory if it is feasible and could offer a performance boost.